# Why are my ggplot2 aesthetics the wrong length?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to average reps of data, subset one treatment, then make a bar graph of the response and another factor. My plot ends up not working. Any help would be much appreciated.

My data:

```
data <- structure(list(Sample = c(1011L, 1012L, 1014L, 1024L, 1025L, 
1026L), Collection = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), Irrigation = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Rate1", "Rate2", "Rate3", "Rate4", "Rate5"
), class = "factor"), Variety = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("Hodag", "Lamoka", "Snowden"), class = "factor"), 
Suc = c(0.7333, 0.4717, 0.5883, 0.6783, 0.8283, 0.6833), 
Gluc = c(0.03, 0.04, 0.043, 0.075, 0.057, 0.087), L = c(59.48, 
57.59, 59.25, 66.45, 68.29, 65.65), a = c(4.36, 6.85, 3.43, 
1.7, 0.78, 2.84), b = c(26.82, 27.6, 26.2, 26.14, 25.37, 
27.19), NoDefect = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 92L, 100L, 100L), 
Defect = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Averaging between reps:

```
dataAvgSuc <- data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Collection, Irrigation, Variety) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(meanSuc=mean(Suc))
```

Made 'Collection' a factor:

```
dataAvgSuc$Collection <- as.factor(dataAvgSuc$Collection)
```

Subset by variety:

```
subLamoka <- subset(dataAvgSuc, Variety=="Lamoka")
subHodag <- subset(dataAvgSuc, Variety=="Hodag")
subSnowden <- subset(dataAvgSuc, Variety=="Snowden")
```

Attempted ggplot:

```
sucPlot <-ggplot(data=subLamoka, aes(x=dataAvgSuc$Collection, 
y=meanSuc)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Error code:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): 
x, y
```

However, both the x and y have 30 entries when I look at them.

Comment: Don't use `$` in the `tidyverse`.

Comment: subLamoka, the source of your y, has 2 observations, while the x from dataAvgSuc$Collection has 6. Did you mean Collection instead of dataAvgSuc$Collection, thus using the version from subLamoka? Or perhaps you want `ggplot(data=dataAvgSuc, aes(x=Variety, fill = Collection, y=meanSuc)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")`

Comment: @JonSpring Thanks for the reply! The plot that you shared is a little off from what I'd like. I want to eventually have a ggplot with Suc on the Y axis and the collection on the x axis for each of the three varieties. Changing dataAvgSuc$Collection to just Collection made the function work (I think so), but my plot doesn't have the correct values. I think that the meanSuc should be somewhere between 0.4 and 0.8, as that is the range of values it's drawing from, but here it's coming up as greater than 3. Any idea if I'm doing something wrong with getting my means?

Comment: @Trev it might help to clarify what you want in your desired plot. did you want meanSuc on your y axis? right now, within each variety, you have multiple meanSuc values for a given collection. for example, subLamoka has 2 meanSuc values for Collection #1 (2 different irrigation rates); did you want those added together (.733+.828=1.5)? could that be what you are seeing for your higher numbers?

Comment: @Ben thanks for the response! I would like meanSuc on my y axis and the two collections on the x axis. I would like to have one of these graphs for each of the 3 varieties. What you mentioned sounds like it could be the problem; I am ignoring the different irrigation rates for now (non-significant factor) and would like those averaged together. Do you have an idea as to how I'd do that? Thanks again!

Comment: if you would like to ignore the irrigation rates for now, then you don't need to include the variable 'Irrigation' in group_by: just do group_by(Collection, Variety)...also, instead of subsetting the data based on Variety, you can use facet_wrap to show a separate graph for each Variety (see suggested answer by Jonni). the only change would be removing Irrigation...is this what you had in mind?

Comment: That completely solved it, it was the irrigation variable causing issues. I wasn't familiar with the facet_wrap function until now, but that seems much more efficient than subsetting everything. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Trev,

Had some trouble re-generating the issue as the sample data provided are for just 6 observations, not 30. So not sure if the below solution would work for you or not.

I used the code you supplied to create the dataframe:

```
data <- structure(list(Sample = c(1011L, 1012L, 1014L, 1024L, 1025L, 1026L), 
        Collection = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1",                                                                                               
        "2"), class = "factor"), 
        Irrigation = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L,5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Rate1", "Rate2", 
        "Rate3", "Rate4", "Rate5"                                                                                                
         ), class = "factor"), Variety = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L,                                                                                                                                               
        1L), .Label = c("Hodag", "Lamoka", "Snowden"), class = "factor"), 
                   Suc = c(0.7333, 0.4717, 0.5883, 0.6783, 0.8283, 0.6833), 
                   Gluc = c(0.03, 0.04, 0.043, 0.075, 0.057, 0.087),
                   L = c(59.48, 57.59, 59.25, 66.45, 68.29, 65.65), 
                   a = c(4.36, 6.85, 3.43, 1.7, 0.78, 2.84),
                   b = c(26.82, 27.6, 26.2, 26.14, 25.37,27.19),
                   NoDefect = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 92L, 100L, 100L), 
                   Defect = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L)), 
       row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


data$Collection
```

However, your Collection factor is defined with two levels but only one is shown in the example. Perhaps this could be why the averages were coming out greater than 1?I modified the code below to have 2 levels of collection represented in the data.

```
data2 <- structure(list(Sample = c(1011L, 1012L, 1014L, 1024L, 1025L, 1026L), 
        Collection = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1",                                                                                               
        "2"), class = "factor"), 
        Irrigation = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L,5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Rate1", "Rate2", 
        "Rate3", "Rate4", "Rate5"                                                                                                
         ), class = "factor"), Variety = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L,                                                                                                                                               
        1L), .Label = c("Hodag", "Lamoka", "Snowden"), class = "factor"), 
                   Suc = c(0.7333, 0.4717, 0.5883, 0.6783, 0.8283, 0.6833), 
                   Gluc = c(0.03, 0.04, 0.043, 0.075, 0.057, 0.087),
                   L = c(59.48, 57.59, 59.25, 66.45, 68.29, 65.65), 
                   a = c(4.36, 6.85, 3.43, 1.7, 0.78, 2.84),
                   b = c(26.82, 27.6, 26.2, 26.14, 25.37,27.19),
                   NoDefect = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 92L, 100L, 100L), 
                   Defect = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L)), 
       row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


data2$Collection
```

Since you're using dplyr just keep piping that object into ggplot-- I don't think you would need to create subsets of new dataframes, but can instead graph them all separately with a **facet_wrap** command. I also am using *geom_col* instead of geom_bar, which the latter is generally trying to graph count data. Since you want to plot an average, geom_col may be better. Also since the example below is piping to the next line, the "data=" definition typically used in ggplot commands is not needed.

First with data:

```
data %>%
        dplyr::group_by(Collection,Irrigation, Variety) %>%
        dplyr::summarise(meanSuc=mean(Suc)) %>% 
          ggplot(aes(x = Collection, y = meanSuc)) +
            geom_col() +
             facet_wrap(.~Variety)
```

Incorporate Irrigation:

```
data %>%
        dplyr::group_by(Collection,Irrigation, Variety) %>%
        dplyr::summarise(meanSuc=mean(Suc)) %>% 
           ggplot(aes(x = Collection, y = meanSuc, fill = Irrigation)) +
             geom_col() +
              facet_wrap(.~Variety)
```

And using data2 instead, as defined above, will produce the Collection levels 1 and 2 side by side on the graph. With this method I was able to generate a result and all averages were less than 1, between .4~.8